Prisma MongoDB returns null when accessing the newly created data for the first time
I am developing a React web app with Clerk authentication. When I log in and redirected to the user page, the service that is in useCallback which is declared in useEffect calls to the backend to get the ID of the user using the externalUserId from clerk. It returns null but when I refresh the page it returns the ID of the user. Any idea what's causing this?
Here's the code in the backend that handles the prisma call:
getSelfId: async (externalUserId: string) => {
  if (!externalUserId) return;

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      externalUserId: externalUserId,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
    },
  });

  return user;
},

Here's the code also in the backend that handles the router:
router.get("/:id", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserService.getSelfId(req.params.id);

    if (user) {
      return res.status(200).json({ user });
    } else {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Error! User not found." });
    }
  } catch (err: any) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message,
      err,
    });
  }
});

Here's the useCallback that calls the endpoint:
const getSelfId = useCallback(async () => {
  if (!isSignedIn) return;

  const self = await UserService.getSelfId(user.id);

  if (self) {
    setUserId(self.id);
  } else {
    toast.error("Server error! Please try again later.");
  }
}, [user, isSignedIn]);

This is the useEffect:
useEffect(() => {
  getSelfId();
}, [getSelfId]);

I tried console.log the result of the prisma call but it returns null.
Screenshot of the null issue:

But when I refreshed the page it returns the ID of the user.
Screenshot of the id of user:

For clarification, this is where I console.log the output:
getSelfId: async (externalUserId: string) => {
  if (!externalUserId) return;

  const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
    where: {
      externalUserId: externalUserId,
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
    },
  });

  console.log(`External UserId: ${externalUserId} | User: ${user}`);

  return user;
},

I suspect that it might be because this is the first call in the MongoDB. But I am not sure; any help would be great. Thanks in advance!
